Oracle truncate table in different user not working despite grants and public synonym without specifying actual user of the table
We upgraded Oracle from 11g to 19c, and we are trying to truncate a table from user1 which is owned by user2. We have the necessary ALTER grants, a synonym for the table in user1, and a public synonym. We are able to truncate the table by specifying the schema, i.e., 'user2.table'. However, we couldn't truncate it directly without prefixing it with user2.
We tried to re-create the public synonym, then created a synonym in user1, and provided the grants again by revoking the existing ones. No luck.
We are expecting to truncate the table without specifying the user2 prefix. Truncating the table without specifying the user2 prefix worked fine in Oracle 11g.
I couldn't find any changes related to this in the Oracle documentation. So, I doubt I'm missing something.

The Oracle 19c create synonym documentation says:

You can refer to synonyms in the following DML statements: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, FLASHBACK TABLE, EXPLAIN PLAN, LOCK TABLE, MERGE, and CALL .
You can refer to synonyms in the following DDL statements: AUDIT, NOAUDIT, GRANT, REVOKE, and COMMENT.

You therefore cannot refer to a synonym in the TRUNCATE statement (which is DDL).
The Oracle 11gR2 documentation said the same thing, so it seems unlikely it was working as you think in that version.
This question has an answer with a PL/SQL approach to do this. You can also create a procedure within the user2 schema to do the truncate, and grant execute on that to user - which would avoid needing the more powerful truncate any table you're presumably relying on now.
